# Installing new version of gnu make without compiling on Linux Lite

Tags: linux, upgrade, gnu-make

I'm on Linux Lite 5.8.
The installed version of gnu make is 4.2.1 but the latest gnu make version is 4.4.1.
Is there a simple way to install this latest version without it being to compile from source?

I found this post https://askubuntu.com/a/1386772/1326 which seems to point to a deb package for 4.3 but the repository link no longer works and I was really hoping to get the latest version of gnu make.

Comment: If you just need an updated `make`, then I'd build it from source. Just make sure that you don't install it over the system version.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you **need** GNU make 4.4? (or 4.3)?  Is there any new feature you actually require or a bug fix that resolves an actual problem you are having? or is it just "bigger version number = more better"?   BTW, Debian has GNU make 4.3 packaged, you could download the debian source for that and re-build it for ubuntu - but I still wouldn't recommend doing so unless you had a real reason to upgrade.

Comment: Also worth noting - you are using a distro based on the Long Term Support (LTS) version of Ubuntu. Wanting the "latest and greatest" stuff is contrary to the entire point of an LTS distro, as the focus of an LTS is on stability (in the sense of "doesn't change for years, aside from security fixes"). If you want the most up-to-date packages or just recent versions, then use either the latest six-monthly release of Ubuntu (or a distro based on it), or a rolling release distro like Arch, or Debian Sid (which has been a "rolling (pre-)release" since the mid 90s, long before it became fashionable).

Comment: I guess I can uninstall the systems one

Comment: @cas I am unable to upgrade to a newer version of linux lite. There is no way to upgrade from 5 to 6 unfortunately.
I was trying to do a simple number comparison and noticed that make 4.4 has `intcmp` which really does what I need, I no longer have to use filter or filter-out to mimic comparisons, that was one of the reasons I wanted this and also in my company there are many mac users that can quickly upgrade to 4.4.1 by just using brew.

Comment: I know nothing about Linux Lite other than that it's based on Ubuntu LTS (and I only know that because I googled it)....but it seems to me that being able to upgrade from one version of a distro to the next should be a basic feature, especially for one based on Ubuntu (which was, in turn, based on Debian which pioneered in-place upgrades).  Is it really not possible?  If not, then perhaps you should use a less "lite" distro - perhaps Ubuntu itself or Mint.   This seems like a good option for you anyway, since you seem to dislike the doesn't-change nature of stable LTS distros.

Comment: @cas my linux knowledge is limited and I went with linux lite because of it's promise of being light. You can see here what they say about moving from one version to another: https://www.linuxliteos.com/forums/updates/upgrade-from-5-6-to-6/
Next time I might try ubuntu if I can change the layout to a more windows feel :)

Comment: FTR, @cas, _"Is there any particular reason why you **need** GNU make 4.4?"_ -- for me it was `.WAIT`.

Answer (score 2):

Make 4.4 [isn’t available as a package for any release of Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/make-dfsg), not even in a PPA. So your only option, short of getting someone else to package it for you, is to compile it yourself.